# Open the same app instance

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a simple, one Activity application.
The problem is that, if i press the BACK button, the application is minimized, but if i try to launch it again, another instance is started.
I know this because my app has plays a sound stream even if is minimized.

How can i maximize the already running instance when trying to launch it ?

I've tried with the code below, but is not working.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: If you have two instances - does your minimized app still play a sound stream when the 2nd instance is started?

Comment: Thanks guys. I've made the object a field of the class, and i've called stop() and release() methods on the MediaPlayer object from the onPause() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android handles this for you.  What is probably happening is you're replicating your objects in `onCreate` thus the "appearance" of 2 activities via a 2nd sound stream.

Comment: It would be correct to create the objects in `onCreate()`. The OP is probably playing a *new* sound on `onResume()`. When the app is paused, then resumed, the function will have been called twice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the C button ? If it is the "back key" so your application is unload from the system, when you start it again, it opens a new instance.
If you press the 'middle key', normally there is only 3 keys on a Android phone, your application is just paused and put in the background, and when you launch it again, the sytem just put your running application from the background to the foreground. No new instance is opened. There are the methods onPause() and onResume() which are triggered in this case.
Hope it can answer to your question